# SAPUI5 - Expression binding in Aggregation binding Type

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to use expression binding in Aggregation type binding. I have a table and each row in the table has a column that has a sap.m.Select control. I want to bind the select control in each row with different items based on a property of the row.

Below is my sample example:

```html
<Table headerText="Dimensions/Measures" mode="MultiSelect" includeItemInSelection="true" items="{path: 'dataModel>/Fields'}">
  <columns>
    <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Center" visible="true">
      <header>
        <Label text="Dimensions/Measures" />
      </header>
    </Column>
    <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Center" visible="true">
      <header>
        <Label text="Type" />
      </header>
    </Column>
    <Column hAlign="Center" vAlign="Center" visible="true">
      <header>
        <Label text="Role" />
      </header>
    </Column>
  </columns>
  <ColumnListItem>
    <Text text="{dataModel>Fieldname}" />
    <Text text="{= ${dataModel>Aggr_Oper} !== null ? 'Measure' : 'Dimension'}" />
    <Select items="{= ${path: 'dataModel>Aggr_Oper'} !== null ? ${dataModel>/chartConfigData/dimData}: ${dataModel>/chartConfigData/measData}}">
      <core:Item key="{dataModel>key}" text="{dataModel>text}" />
    </Select>
  </ColumnListItem>
</Table>
```

My Data Model looks as below:

```js
{
   "Fields":[
      {
         "AppID":"RP_PROP",
         "AppVariantID":"PropListVariantDemo",
         "Fieldname":"PropertyID",
         "FieldDescription":"PropertyID",
         "Aggr_Oper":null,
         "Filterable":null,
         "Visible":"true",
         "Filter_Val":null,
         "DisplayOrder":1,
         "FieldGroup":null,
         "SubTotal":null,
         "FieldType":null,
         "Sortable":"true",
         "Sort_Op":"ASC",
         "Sort_Order":1,
         "ChartRole":null,
         "BusinessEntity":"BRS"
      },
      {
         "AppID":"RP_PROP",
         "AppVariantID":"PropListVariantDemo",
         "Fieldname":"Description",
         "FieldDescription":"Description",
         "Aggr_Oper":null,
         "Filterable":null,
         "Visible":"true",
         "Filter_Val":null,
         "DisplayOrder":2,
         "FieldGroup":null,
         "SubTotal":null,
         "FieldType":null,
         "Sortable":"true",
         "Sort_Op":null,
         "Sort_Order":null,
         "ChartRole":null,
         "BusinessEntity":"BRS"
      },
      {
         "AppID":"RP_PROP",
         "AppVariantID":"PropListVariantDemo",
         "Fieldname":"PropertyTypeID",
         "FieldDescription":"PropertyTypeID",
         "Aggr_Oper":null,
         "Filterable":null,
         "Visible":"true",
         "Filter_Val":null,
         "DisplayOrder":3,
         "FieldGroup":null,
         "SubTotal":null,
         "FieldType":null,
         "Sortable":"true",
         "Sort_Op":null,
         "Sort_Order":null,
         "ChartRole":null,
         "BusinessEntity":"BRS"
      },
      {
         "AppID":"RP_PROP",
         "AppVariantID":"PropListVariantDemo",
         "Fieldname":"PropertyType",
         "FieldDescription":"PropertyType",
         "Aggr_Oper":null,
         "Filterable":null,
         "Visible":"true",
         "Filter_Val":null,
         "DisplayOrder":4,
         "FieldGroup":null,
         "SubTotal":null,
         "FieldType":null,
         "Sortable":null,
         "Sort_Op":null,
         "Sort_Order":null,
         "ChartRole":null,
         "BusinessEntity":"BRS"
      },
      {
         "AppID":"RP_PROP",
         "AppVariantID":"PropListVariantDemo",
         "Fieldname":"RegionID",
         "FieldDescription":"RegionID",
         "Aggr_Oper":null,
         "Filterable":null,
         "Visible":"true",
         "Filter_Val":null,
         "DisplayOrder":5,
         "FieldGroup":null,
         "SubTotal":null,
         "FieldType":null,
         "Sortable":null,
         "Sort_Op":null,
         "Sort_Order":null,
         "ChartRole":null,
         "BusinessEntity":"BRS"
      },
      {
         "AppID":"RP_PROP",
         "AppVariantID":"PropListVariantDemo",
         "Fieldname":"RegionDescription",
         "FieldDescription":"RegionDescription",
         "Aggr_Oper":null,
         "Filterable":null,
         "Visible":"true",
         "Filter_Val":null,
         "DisplayOrder":6,
         "FieldGroup":null,
         "SubTotal":null,
         "FieldType":null,
         "Sortable":null,
         "Sort_Op":null,
         "Sort_Order":null,
         "ChartRole":null,
         "BusinessEntity":"BRS"
      }
   ],
   "chartConfigData":{
      "dimData":[
         {
            "key":"val1",
            "text":"val1"
         },
         {
            "key":"val2",
            "text":"val2"
         }
      ],
      "measData":[
         {
            "key":"val3",
            "text":"val3"
         },
         {
            "key":"val4",
            "text":"val4"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, dynamic binding paths are not possible. There are some possible workarounds however:

- You can process your model data and add a reference to the appropriate select items list to each row. Use a relative binding path to that reference in your select fields binding.
- You can use a [factory function](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/284a036c8ff943238fb65bf5a2676fb7.html) to create the rows of your table. You can put your row template as [dependant](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html#getDependents) to your table and clone it and configure the selects binding for each row in the factory function
- You can add multiple selects with different bindings to your table and hide all but one in each row by binding the [visible](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html#getVisible) properties of the selects.

Comment: Thanks schnoedel. used the factory function option from above since the number of rows are limited.