# Dynamic Expression Binding on Path for items

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

Is it possible to have a dynamic expression binding on the property Items for a sap.m.table?

Considering:

```
<Table items="{ path: {dynamic expression here}}"/>
```

I tried creating a model in the controller and setting it as a property but it is not reading it. I have followed this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521224/sapui5-expression-binding) answer.

To be specific, I tried:

```
items = {view>/Property1}
```

or

```
items = ${view>/Property1}
```

Has anyone done this or was able to do this? Is this possible? If not, is the only way to do this is to bind the table in the controller?

Comment: It's not possible. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078071/sapui5-expression-binding-in-aggregation-binding-type) can help you.

Comment: I figured as much. Thanks @I.B.N.